# Create a color vector from a dataframe in R and create a barplot

Tags: r, plot, vector, colors

I have below dataframe:

| City | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Brisbane | 1657 |
| Melbourne | 7583 |
| Victoria | 5738 |
| Sydney | 9274 |
| NSW | 5938 |
| Adelaide | 8223 |

I want to create a vector from this dataframe by giving different colors to each city. Then I need to plot a barplot City~Cost using that given colors.

I tried below code to create the vector:

```
cv <- dColorVector(df$City, colorScale = "plasma")
```

But get an error: could not find function "dColorVector"

Pls help!

Comment: I got this from a blog. Anyhow I cannot think of any code to get this vector. Tried using rainbow(), but still cannot connect it with the dataframe

Comment: Looks like it's from a Bioconductor package - https://rdrr.io/bioc/DepecheR/man/dColorVector.html - installation instructions here - http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DepecheR.html

Comment: Not that you'd need all those extra packages to do a barplot - `barplot(dat$Cost, names.arg=dat$City, col=palette("R3"))` for instance will do it fine.

Comment: I will be still need the vector though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can easily get the same result directly the `viridis` package, which is what `dColorVector` uses anyway.

```r
library(viridis)

cv <- plasma(length(df$City))

cv
#> [1] "#0D0887FF" "#6A00A8FF" "#B12A90FF" "#E16462FF" "#FCA636FF" "#F0F921FF"

barplot(Cost ~ City, data = df, col = cv)
```

[image]